# Managing the Header List in Android

Tags: android, list, header

I want to display a message in the Header of the List before I get any data in the List from the WebService.

I am able to display the data via this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    searchContactsResponseList.add(new SearchContactsBean());
}

LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
header_List = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null); 

contactsList(my listview Obj).addHeaderView(header_List);

if(searchContactsResponseList.size() > 0) {
        if(contactsList.getHeaderViewsCount() > 0)
            contactsList.removeHeaderView(header_List); 
        contactsList.setAdapter(searchContactsAdapter);
}
```

Now I want this:
When I get the data from the WebService I display it, it is working perfectly,
but when I search for the name that doesn't exist in the response again I want to show the same massage that I used to show initially.

I am getting some exception saying that the setAdapter method already exists.

Any Clue!!!

Thanks
david